# Вылетает Android Studio при открытии design раздела xml файлов ( activity_main.xml )

Tags: android, android-studio

Недавно скачал Android Studio, чтобы разрабатывать свои приложения. Но тут у меня появилась проблема. При открытии design раздела в макетах ( например, activity_main.xml ) у меня просто вылетает.

[Видео, где вылетает студия](https://yadi.sk/i/IfEFNo9uArh4Qg)

[idea.log](https://yadi.sk/d/-LpRMtV8UBrtGQ)

Ниже характеристики ноутбука

Windows 7 64bit

HP Pavilion dv6-6b10er

8 gb RAM

A8-3510mx ( 4 ядра, 4 потока, 1.8 Ггц )

Radeon HD6620g

Comment: Загляните в `Event Log` ругается на какие то модули. Это будет полезней чем, конфигурация компьютера или видео падения.

Comment: Ни на что не ругается. Просто приложение закрывается и все. Не выдает никаких ошибок

Comment: а нет, выдало. Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules: My Application. Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.

Comment: Кстати такая же ситуация, у тебя проблема решилась?